# How does share_ptr release memory when main ends?

Tags: c++, operating-system

It is said that this is related to threads, I don't know much about OS.Thanks for your Answers.

```
int main(){
    shared_ptr<int> p = make_shared<int>(1024);
    //do nothing,end my program
}
```

use_count() will be 1 if I check in main，how to be 0？Or wo need to release operation.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing to do with the OS, the `shared_ptr` destructor frees the memory and since `p` is a local variable the scope will end (i.e call destructor) when main ends.

Comment: It may be that my understanding is wrong. Isn't the destructor called only when the counter is 0?

Comment: When main ends, p leaves the scope, then the counter is decremented by 1? Is this understood?

Comment: This is correct, the reference counter in this case will reach zero when it leaves scope, thus destroying the object it owns.